# Where is Week04.Monad?

Tags: plutus-pioneer-program, cabal

Doing Week 04 of cohort 3 Plutus Pioneers here.

In the repl inside the nix shell, inside ~/plutus/plutus-pioneer-program/code/week04

Watching PPP 030402 at 34:54 to about 39:59.

When I do

> ```
> :l src/Week04/Either.hs
> ```

I get

> ```
> Prelude Data.Char Text.Read Week04.Either> import Week04.Either
> Prelude Data.Char Text.Read Week04.Either> :l src/Week04/Either.hs
> : warning: [-Wmissing-home-modules]
> These modules are needed for compilation but not listed in your .cabal file's other-modules:
> Week04.Monad
> Ok, two modules loaded.
> Prelude Data.Char Text.Read Week04.Either>
> ```

Oddly, I can directly import Week04.Monad in the repl

> ```
> Prelude Data.Char Text.Read Week04.Either> import Week04.Monad
> Prelude Data.Char Text.Read Week04.Either Week04.Monad> :l src/Week04/Either.hs
> : warning: [-Wmissing-home-modules]
> These modules are needed for compilation but not listed in your .cabal file's other-modules:
> Week04.Monad
> Ok, two modules loaded.
> Prelude Data.Char Text.Read Week04.Either Week04.Monad>
> ```

and Week04.Monad IS part of the plutus-pioneer-program-week04.cabal file

> ```
> library
>   hs-source-dirs:      src
>   exposed-modules:     Week04.Contract
>                      , Week04.Either
>                      , Week04.Homework
>                      , Week04.Maybe
>                      , Week04.Monad
>                      , Week04.Trace
>                      , Week04.Writer
>   other-modules:       Week04.Vesting
>   build-depends:       aeson
>                      , base ^>=4.14.1.0
>                      , containers
>                      , data-default
>                      , freer-extras
>                      , playground-common
>                      , plutus-contract
>                      , plutus-ledger
>                      , plutus-ledger-api
>                      , plutus-ledger-constraints
>                      , plutus-tx-plugin
>                      , plutus-tx
>                      , text
>   default-language:    Haskell2010
> ```

but it is listed under "exposed-modules" rather than "other-modules". If I manually edit to put it under other-modules (and remove it from exposed-modules, and various combinations), and even if I exit (:q) and re-enter the repl, the error persists, and I cannot replicate what is being demonstrated in the video.

Any guidance? Thanks.

Comment: Here: Prelude Data.Char Text.Read Week04.Either> import Week04.Either 
You don't need neither "import Wee04.Either" nor ":l src/Week04/Either.hs" because it is already loaded. (See left side of ">" )

Comment: That doesn't seem to make any difference. If I leave the repl and re-enter, I can produce this: 

Prelude Week04.Contract> :l src/Week04/Either.hs

<no location info>: warning: [-Wmissing-home-modules]
    These modules are needed for compilation but not listed in your .cabal file's other-modules: 
        Week04.Monad
Ok, two modules loaded.
Prelude Week04.Either> 

And shouldn't cabal/nix/Haskell handle an attempted double import painlessly?

Comment: I see that "import Week04.Either" works, loading module Week04.Either. Why do you want do ":l src/Week04/Either.hs " ?

Comment: Just wanted to add that I also receive that error even when I add Week04.Monad to other-modules. While it is annoying that the warning appears, you can still follow along with what Lars does in the video

Comment: Yes, I see now that I can follow along even with the error, probably related to exiting and re-entering either the repl or my nix shell. Was getting errors with everything prior to that. As to adding "Week04.Either" vs ":l src/Week04/Either.hs" I think that has to do with my current directory, perhaps whether the module is compiled, and some ambiguity - do you (@kindofdev) mean "import ..." or ":l ..."?

Comment: I meant that using import Week04.Either works

Answer (score 0):

You can find `Week04.Monad` [here](https://github.com/input-output-hk/plutus-pioneer-program/blob/main/code/week04/src/Week04/Monad.hs).